# How to execute PL/SQL that already exists. (Oracle APEX 21.1)

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

What I do to display the result of PL/SQL "PR_TEXT_CONCAT"?

I want display that result to Page3. This page has 3 Text Fields and 1 Button.

Enter text in `P3_TEXT1` and `P3_TEXT2`, and press the button (`P3_EXECUTE`), show the string `P3_TEXT1 + P3_TEXT2` on `P3_TEXTOUT`.
The procedure was created with the following SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_TEXT_CONCAT
{
  PARAM1 IN VERCHAR2,
  PARAM2 IN VERCHAR2, PARAM2 IN VERCHAR2,
  PARAMOUT OUT VERCHAR2
}
IS
BEGIN
    PARAMOUT := 'SHOP: ' || PARAM1 || '+' || PARAM2;
END;
```

---Added--
It is written in PL/SQL Dynamic Content region.
`Source - PL/SQL Code: :PARAMOUT := PR_TEXT_CONCAT;`

Comment: It caused an Error  XD
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments

Comment: I need help to how to set parameter / get return value from PL/SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is how I did

- created 3 items + 1 button
- created one page process (1)
- run the page
- input some text into fields
- clicked the button saw the output(2)

(1) inside page process `:P2_TEXTOUT := :P2_TEXT1 || :P2_TEXT2;`

[image]

(2) example

[image]

> 2nd way:

```
create or replace function textOut (vText_1 in varchar2, vText_2 in varchar2) 
return varchar2 is

vTextOut varchar2(20);

begin

vTextOut := vText_1 || vText_2;

return vTextOut;
end;
```

then call this function in your page process source;

```
select textOut (:p2_text1, :p2_text2) into :p2_textout from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But to tell you the truth, I want to execute more harder for me to understand stored procedure. (And that SQL statement changes without my knowledge. Except for the number of parameters and the return value type.) Right now I'm using a simple PL/SQL for testing.

Comment: no problem, I'm editing the answer

Comment: Thank you again!
But it's Create procedure command show me a error, when I run it...
I just try to clear my mistakes and return respond you. Thank you  :)

Comment: THANK YOU VERRRY MUCH!!!
I forgot to change the Create statement word from procedure to function!
It worked very well. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do this with a stored procedure. Note that there were some errors in your code (curly braces and "VERCHAR" are both not used in oracle)

1. Create the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_TEXT_CONCAT
(
  PARAM1 IN VARCHAR2,
  PARAM2 IN VARCHAR2,
  PARAMOUT OUT VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
    PARAMOUT := 'SHOP: ' || PARAM1 || '+' || PARAM2;
END;
/
```

2. Create the apex page

- Create a region with 3 items: P1_ITEM1, P1_ITEM2 and P1_ITEM3
- Create a region button with action "Submit Page"
- Create a page process with point "Processing" and code

```
PR_TEXT_CONCAT
(
  PARAM1 => :P1_ITEM1,
  PARAM2 => :P1_ITEM2,
  PARAMOUT => :P1_ITEM3
);
```

This should do. Put a value in item 1 and item 2 and click the button. item 3 will contain the value returned from the stored proc